# Why do setState and useState not run inside event listener callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, use-state, setstate

I have come across a very weird problem. I have a function that is being used as a callback for an eventListener. This callback has a setState call inside it.

The weird thing is that if I pass the function as a prop to another component and call it in the `onClick` handler, the `setState` call executes and its callback prints to the console.

When I'm using it as the callback to the eventListener, on the event being fired, the function is running, but the `setState` inside it does not run!

No error or warning is thrown on the console.

Code:

Utils.js

```js
import { EventEmitter } from 'fbemitter';

const emitter = new EventEmitter();
```

CurrentFile.jsx

```js
import { emitter } from './Utils';

class ComponentWithListener extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selections: this.props.selections
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    emitter.addListener('resetSelections', () => this.resetSelections());
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    emitter.removeAllListeners('resetSelections');
  }

  resetSelections = () => {
    console.log('resetSelections() called');

    this.setState({ selections: this.props.initialSelections }, () => {
      console.log('successfully reset selections');
      someFunctionCall();
    });
  }
}
```

OtherFile.jsx

```js
import { emitter } from './Utils';

class OtherFile extends React.Component {
  // ..state declaration and other functions
  
  resetStoredFilters = () => {
    // do some things
    emitter.emit('resetSelections');
  }

  // other functions and render()
}
```

So here, whenever `resetStoredFilter()` is run, the `setState` inside `resetSelections()` is not run, and the output I get on console for `resetSelections()` is:

```
resetSelections() called
```

`someFunctionCall()` runs.

Compare this to when I pass `resetSelections` as a prop to a child component and call it from inside an `onClick` handler from inside the child component:

```js
// body of some function inside child component
onClick={resetSelections}
```

When this element is clicked inside the child component, the output I get on the console for `resetSelection()` is:

```
resetSelections() called
successfully reset selections
```

`someFunctionCall()` does not run.

I even tried using functional components and `useState` hook in `CurrentFile.jsx` to check if that makes a difference. I see the same issue still.

Why does this happen? And how to make the `setState` run in eventListener callbacks?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox for this? I hope the value is actually changing,